# How do you call a function inside a module.exports = function () in another class?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the following example, simply putting `module.exports = {save}` on the *jsFileName.js* file functions is not an option here, due to limitations on my codebase. Is this possible to access the function from the export, inside of *callFunctionFromAboveFile.js* shown below? See the below example of how I'd like to access that function. I've searched all the other answers to questions similar but they all mention using the exports differently as I stated in my first line above.

If there is a way to access it as it is shown, please share your answer or details as to why it's not possible. Also, other ways to handle this would be helpful but I can't change the class up much given the limitation to the codebase.

jsFileName.js

```js
module.exports = function (JsFileName) {
    JsFileName.save = function (stuff) {}
}
```

callFunctionFromAboveFile.js

```js
const JsFileName = require('jsFileName');
// TODO I'm not sure how this would call the save() w/out using exports differently.
// TODO I have to use exports as I've posted it in jsFileName.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default export of `jsFileName.js` is a function that adds functions to its parameter `JsFileName`.
Apparently, you can pass any object which is then modified to act as the module's exports.

That means: Pass any object you want to have the modules' functionality. Note that the object is not returned, so you have to keep the reference to it yourself.

```js
// callFunctionFromAboveFile.js
const JsFileName = {};
require("jsFileName") // Get default export (the function)
  (JsFileName); // Call with any object you want to "enhance"

JsFileName.save(/*...*/);
```

Comment: Appreciate the quick response. I tried this but I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of undefined`.

Comment: Ah my bad, I'll correct it.